# Can't load file to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I'm a database newbie. I'm currently trying to create a db with [databases](https://github.com/encode/databases) and mysql+aiomysql. I need to initialize some tables by reading local csv files.

First of all, I make a connection to the database I previously created with:

```
database = Database('mysql+aiomysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{db}?local-infile=1'.format(
host='xxx',
user='xxx',
passwd='xxx',
db='xxx'))
await database.connect()
```

with `?local-infile=1` to enable client's side local data (I also experimented with `?allowLoadLocalInfile=true`). Afterwards, I executed `SET GLOBAL local_infile = true` to enable local data on server's side. Finally, I also made sure to set `secure-file-priv = ""`.

Nonetheless, when I execute `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file INTO TABLE table` I get the error:

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (3948, 'Loading local data is disabled;
> this must be enabled on both the client and server sides')

Tried also to add `LOCAL` in the `LOAD` command above without any luck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: mysql is usuall configure to allow file only from one directory

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/bulk-insert-mysql/

Comment: The LOAD DATA command has some specific security requirements that must be met. See [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-security-requirements) and make sure you have everything covered.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I can confirm that everything listed there has been done

Answer (score 0):

Find your my.cnf file (usually in /etc/my.cnf, /etc/mysql/my.cnf, or /usr/local/etc/my.cnf) then add these lines:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile
secure-file-priv = "/directory/you/wish/to/load/files/"

[mysql]
local-infile
```

Then restart mysql and try again.